# Hide a div behind

Tags: html, css, fixed, behind

I try to do a simple think but I am stuck.
I have a div "scrolling" with a fixed position. When I scroll the page, I want that the div "scrolling" goes behind all other div below.

I put an exemple in : [exemple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maxa88/huoxfyn5/41/)

```
.scrolling{
  top: 230px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

doable with `z-index`. But for the z-index to work, it must be `position: absolute`, `position:fixed`, or `position:relative`.

```css
.top{
  width:auto;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  height:300px;  
    background-image: linear-gradient(pink, green);
}
.scrolling{
  top: 230px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling">
  SCROLL
  <br>
  I want to stay behind the div grey
</div>

<div style="width:auto; height:50px; background-color:grey;position:relative;z-index:5">

</div>
  
<div style="width:auto; height:350px; background-color:grey;position:relative;z-index:5">
  I want to be in displayed in front
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure a (z index) is what you want to use here.

I updated your fiddle below. Z index allows you to position from front to back.

```
<div class="top">
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
  <div>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scrolling">
  SCROLL
  <br>
  I want to stay behind the div grey
</div>


<div class="front" style="width:auto; height:350px; background-color:grey;">
  I want to be in displayed in front
</div>

.top{
  width:auto;
  background-attachment: fixed; 
  height:300px;  
  background-image: linear-gradient(pink, green);
  z-index: 0;
}
.scrolling{
  top: 230px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
.front{
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That puts the element behind *everything*, thus never visible. If you take a look at OP's provided JSFiddle, you'll see that the element should be visible until scrolled over by the gray element.

Comment: After I posted that I actually went into the fiddle and provided the correct code. 
You are right.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to understand concepts like `z-index` and/or how the stacking order works. There are great articles that will explain z-index, but one in particular I really enjoy is [What no one told you about z-index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

A snippet from the referenced article above:

> When you introduce the position property into the mix, any positioned elements (and their children) are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements. (To say an element is “positioned” means that it has a position value other than static, e.g., relative, absolute, etc.)

Interestingly enough, there's a CSS3 property that does something similar. You can address your issue, without the need of explicitly applying a z-index, by using `transform`.

For example, if we apply `transform: translateX(0)` to your JSFiddle, you'll see that the gray div now sits above your text. Here's an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh94Lbad/

```
<div style="width:auto; height:50px; background-color:grey; transform: translateX(0)"></div>
<div style="width:auto; height:350px; background-color:grey;transform: translateX(0)">I want to be in displayed in front</div>
```

The reason `transform` works (by modifying the stacking context) is explained in the spec:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, any value other than none for the transform property results in the creation of a stacking context. Implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it were a positioned element with z-index: 0. If an element with a transform is positioned, the z-index property applies as described in [CSS2], except that auto is treated as 0 since a new stacking context is always created.

**Edit**: As [pointed out by @TemaniAfif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640839/hide-a-div-behind/53640997?noredirect=1#comment94141980_53640997), it's probably better to explain how this works by explaining the `paint order` of your elements:

> For this you need to consider the painting order (w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order) where you find that transformed element are painted later thus they are above. (in the step (8) )

Comment: the quote is not the correct one to explain the behavior of transform ... you explained that transform create a stacking context which doesn't imply that it should be above the other element. For this you need to consider the painting order (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#painting-order) where you find that transformed element are painted later thus they are above. (in the step  (8) )

Comment: Probably the use of *not correct* isn't the right, but I would say it's not accurate as it doesn't explain that it should be painted after other element

Comment: That's a great point :) I tend to think of stacking context/paint order as one, as they're so closely related. But the technical explanation of _why_ transform affects the rendering is addressed by the paint order and the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use more z-index to element that you want to be seen and use less z-index to element "behind".